# Make thumbnail images on blogger homepage clickable

Tags: blogger, clickable

i would like to have only the thumbnail images on the blog homepage clickable and linked to its article page

Thanks
http://jpst.it/y1x0

Comment: How is this question related to programming? What have you tried so far? Can you please give some source code where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you must add your code into the question.

i took the code from your link and updated it with the hyperlink.

**Try this**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[

    function removeHtmlTag(strx, chop) {
        if (strx.indexOf("<") != -1)

        {
            var s = strx.split("<");
            for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                if (s[i].indexOf(">") != -1) {
                    s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">") + 1, s[i].length);

                }

            }

            strx = s.join("");

        }

        chop = (chop < strx.length - 1) ? chop : strx.length - 2;
        while (strx.charAt(chop - 1) != ' ' && strx.indexOf(' ', chop) != -1) chop++;
        strx = strx.substring(0, chop - 1);
        return strx + ' ';
    }


    function createSummaryAndThumb(pID) {
        var div = document.getElementById(pID);
        var imgtag = "";
        var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
        var summ = summary_noimg;


        if (img.length >= 1) {
            imgtag = '<div id="thumbnail"><div class="thumbnail"><a expr:href='data:post.url'><img src="' + img[0].src + '" width="' + img_thumb_width + 'px" height="' + img_thumb_height + 'px"/></a></div></div>';
            summ = summary_img;

        }


        var summary = imgtag + '<p>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML, summ) + '</p>';

        div.innerHTML = summary;



    }

    //]]>
    </script>
```

In your script i only added the hyperlink, check it below:

```
<a expr:href='data:post.url'><img src="' + img[0].src + '" width="' + img_thumb_width + 'px" height="' + img_thumb_height + 'px"/></a>
```

Comment: i did that by myself but the problem is that the image size change :/

Comment: i find this code before that one : 
<script type='text/javascript'>var thumbnail_mode = &quot;float-right&quot; ;
summary_noimg = 90;
summary_img = 90;
img_thumb_height = 161;
img_thumb_width = 210;
</script>