# Blogger: clickable thumbnail with auto readmore

Tags: javascript, blogger

I am trying to make thumbnail in post summary clickable and leading to the post. I am using script for auto read more available widely and I found here a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526771/make-thumbnail-images-on-blogger-homepage-clickable#) that could answer my question, but it is not working properly - as soon as I add ... part my homepage starts showing whole posts. This is what I have currently:

```js
< script type = 'text/javascript' >
  //<![CDATA[
  function removeHtmlTag(strx, chop) {
    if (strx.indexOf("<") != -1) {
      var s = strx.split("<");
      for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i].indexOf(">") != -1) {
          s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">") + 1, s[i].length);
        }
      }
      strx = s.join("");
    }
    chop = (chop < strx.length - 1) ? chop : strx.length - 2;
    while (strx.charAt(chop - 1) != ' ' && strx.indexOf(' ', chop) != -1) chop++;
    strx = strx.substring(0, chop - 1);
    return strx + '...';
  }

function ThumbnailSummary(pID) {
  var div = document.getElementById(pID);
  var imgtag = "";
  var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
  var summ = summary_noimg;
  if (img.length >= 1) {
    imgtag = '<div class="crop-thumb"><img src="' + img[0].src + '" width="' + img_thumb_width + 'px" height="' + img_thumb_height + 'px"/></div>';
    summ = summary_img;
  }
  var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML, summ) + '</div>';
  div.innerHTML = summary;
}
//]]>
</script>
```

And then in the body:

```html
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
    <div expr:id='&quot;summary&quot; + data:post.id' style='text-align: justify'>
      <data:post.body/>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      ThumbnailSummary
        ( & quot; summary < data: post.id / > & quot;);
    </script>
    <div class='readmore-box'>
      <a class='readmore-button' expr:href='data:post.url'>CZYTAJ DALEJ...</a>
    </div>
  </b:if>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
  <data:post.body/>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
  <data:post.body/>
</b:if>
```

Do I need to amend the second part somehow to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove spaces from `ThumbnailSummary` argument

```
ThumbnailSummary
        ( & quot; summary < data: post.id / > & quot;);
```

To pass valid argument and get post id from Blogger.

Your code should be

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
   <a expr:href='data:post.url'>
    <div expr:id='&quot;summary&quot; + data:post.id' style='text-align: justify'>
      <data:post.body/>
    </div>
   </a>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      ThumbnailSummary( &quot;summary<data:post.id/>&quot; );
    </script>
    <div class='readmore-box'>
      <a class='readmore-button' expr:href='data:post.url'>CZYTAJ DALEJ...</a>
    </div>
  </b:if>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
  <data:post.body/>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
  <data:post.body/>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Apologies, seems like those spaces were added by editor. Maybe I should put it in other words: the above code works fine but it only makes titles clickable. I tried to change it like this: `<div class="crop-thumb"><a expr:href='data:post.url'><img src="' + img[0].src + '" width="' + img_thumb_width + 'px" height="' + img_thumb_height + 'px"/></a></div>` but then there are no post summaries anymore and I am getting whole posts instead

Comment: You can't get `data:post.url` outside Blog1 widget so wrap post body code with post link instead, see update.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense